# JS ou Jquery passar dois array's, input text e input check quando marcado

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Preciso pegar o campo texto quando o input check estiver marcado. O checked eu ja consigo pegar no meu controlador. Mas o campo texto não. Eles são gerados pelo banco e por tanto precisam ser tratados como array, pois a quantidade e descrição dos grupos variam sempre de acordo com a peça.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Abaixo mostro como são gerados esses campos:

```
      function CarregaGrupo() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/RTRC_Solucao/CarregaSelectGrupo",
                data: {
                    IdRTRC: $("#Id_Rtrc").val()
                },
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#checkboxesGrupo").empty();

                    $.each(data, function (i, element) {                    
                        if (element.TemGrupo > 0) {
                            $('#checkboxesGrupo').append('<input type="text" name="optionsObsGrupo[]" />  <input type="checkbox" name="optionsGrupo[]" value=' + element.Id + ' checked /> ' + element.Descricao + '<br />');

                        } else {

                            $('#checkboxesGrupo').append('<input type="text" name="optionsObsGrupo[]" />  <input type="checkbox" name="optionsGrupo[]" value=' + element.Id + ' /> ' + element.Descricao + ' <br />');
                        }

                    });

                }
            });
        }
```

> Abaixo mostro como pego o input check:

```
 $("#AdicionarGrupoPeca").click(function () {

        var checkedsGrupo = [];
        var obsGrupo = [];


        $("input[name='optionsGrupo[]']:checked").each(function () {
            checkedsGrupo.push($(this).val());
            obsGrupo.push($("input[type=text][name='optionsObsGrupo']").val());          
        });  


        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/RTRC_Solucao/AdicionarGrupoPeca",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                checkedsGrupo: checkedsGrupo,  
                obsGrupo: obsGrupo,                    
                IdRTRC: $("#Id_Rtrc").val(),
                ObservacaoReposicao: $("#ObservacaoReposicao").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#respostaPecaProduto").addClass("alert alert-success");
                $('#respostaPecaProduto').html('Salvo com sucesso');
                $('#respostaPecaProduto').show();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#respostaPecaProduto').fadeOut('fast');
                }, 1000);
            },
            error: function (request, status, erro) {
                $("#respostaPecaProduto").addClass("alert alert-danger");
                $('#respostaPecaProduto').html('Contato NÃO FOI REMOVIDO!', erro);
                $('#respostaPecaProduto').show();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#respostaPecaProduto').fadeOut('fast');
                }, 1000);
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                CarregaPecas();
                $('#ModalPeca').modal('hide');
            }
        });

    });
```

Asp.Net chega certo os marcados, no entanto chega null ou "" os campos obs (input text)

```
  [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AdicionarGrupoPeca(int[] checkedsGrupo,string[] obsGrupo, int IdRTRC, string ObservacaoReposicao)
        {

            Dao.AdicionarGrupoPeca(checkedsGrupo, obsGrupo, checkedsPeca, obsPeca, IdRTRC, ObservacaoReposicao);
            return Json("Dados salvo com sucesso!!");
        }




HTML

<div class="modal fade in" id="ModalPeca" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Adicionar Peça de Reposição</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">GRUPO:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    @*<select id="Peca_Produto" class="form-control"></select>*@
                                    <div id="checkboxesGrupo">
                                        <!-- AQUI VEM OS CHECKS DAS PEÇAS-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br /><br /><br /><br />
                            <hr />


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <br /><br /><br /><br />
                                <br /><br /><br />
                                <hr />
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Observação:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <textarea id="ObservacaoReposicao" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br /><br /><br /><br />
                            <div id="respostaPecaProduto"></div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="AdicionarGrupoPeca">Atualizar Peça</button>
                                <button type="button" id="fecharModal" class="btn btn-primary">Fechar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Comment: se tem vários input text assim como os checkboxes, deveria usar um `each` para pegar os valores de todos, assim como fez com os checkbox, ou seja, um seletor ocm each para os checkbox e outro para os input text

Comment: @RicardoPontual o problema que é preciso pega somente quando o Check estiver marcado para que os index fiquem iguais. Tipo che[1] = obs[1] . O que não ocorre caso o check não esteja marcado, ele continua a pegar o obs.

Comment: então precisa usar o `this` como referência para pegar os inputs próximos. Pode colocar  na pergunta um exemplo do html com a estrutura que tem dentro do "grupo" para entendermos melhor e poder ajudar a sugerir um seletor que ajude

Comment: Coloquei o HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes, o seletor pode ser feito assim:

`$(this).prev("input:text[name='optionsObsGrupo[]']")`

- usei o `this` para usar o checkbox como referência;
- `prev` para pegar o elemento mais próximo antes do checkbox
- `input:text` queremos o input do tipo text
- `name='optionsObsGrupo[]'` aqui é o nome, e no seu código faltaram os conchetes

Aqui um exemplo funcionando:

```js
$("#AdicionarGrupoPeca").click(function () {

        var checkedsGrupo = [];
        var obsGrupo = [];


        $("input[name='optionsGrupo[]']:checked").each(function () {
            checkedsGrupo.push($(this).val());
            obsGrupo.push($(this).prev("input:text[name='optionsObsGrupo[]']").val());
        });  
        
        alert(obsGrupo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxesGrupo">
  
  <input type="text" name="optionsObsGrupo[]" value="T1" />  
  <input type="checkbox" name="optionsGrupo[]"  /> 
  <br />
  
  <input type="text" name="optionsObsGrupo[]" value="T2" />  
  <input type="checkbox" name="optionsGrupo[]"  /> 
  <br />
  
  <input type="text" name="optionsObsGrupo[]" value="T3" />  
  <input type="checkbox" name="optionsGrupo[]"  /> 
  <br />
  
</div>

<button id="AdicionarGrupoPeca">Testar</button>
```

Comment: PERFEITO. Bendito "prev " ... Valeu Ricardo.